# regex for google search result not work in android

Tags: java, android, regex, web-scraping

I try to scrape google search result with this code

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<h3.*?><a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?</h3>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
```

in android studio its work, but in android devices takes too much time ...

how can i fix that ?

Comment: so there's no error? depending on engine sometimes you have escape `/` => `\/`

Comment: @sweaver2112 no any error i said thats work but need for too much times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your regex causing catastrophic backtracking.

Adding the first `.*?` to an **atomic group** will help.
An atomic group prevents backtracking in that particular group.

```
(?><h3.*?>)<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?<\/h3>
```

See https://regex101.com/r/hl2ARK/1 and try removing the first group to replicate your original regex.

Pretty much everything you need to know about catasrophic backtracking can be found here http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html